# Does the MSBuild SonarQube Runner support C++ projects?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We have Visual Studio Solutions which may consist of C# and C++ (CLI) projects. At the moment we are using the C# and C++ Community Plugins together with the SonarRunner to analyse our code.
Now the C# plugin marks the SonarRunner as deprecated. Does someone know if the MSBuild runner can utilize the C++ Community Plugin?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MSBuild runner uses sonar-runner internally to perform the analysis and publishing of issues to SonarQube server. So everything that sonar-runner supports, should work with MSBuild runner as well. See this thread - [Relationship between SonarQube Runner and SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908012/relationship-between-sonarqube-runner-and-sonarqube-msbuild-runner)